# C++ default allocator - what should happen if the size doesn't equal the size passed to the invocation of allocate?

Tags: c++, std, allocator

**20.6.9:**

```
void deallocate(pointer p, size_type n);
```

- Requires: p shall be a pointer value obtained from allocate(). n shall equal the value passed as the first argument to the invocation of allocate which returned p.
- Effects: Deallocates the storage referenced by p.
- Remarks: Uses ::operator delete(void*) (18.6.1), but it is unspecified when this function is called.

What should happen if `n`doesn't equal the value passed as the first agrgument to the invocation of allocate which returned `p`? Not deallocate? Throw `std::bad_alloc`? ...

**EDIT:**
What I actually meant with "what should happen" was: Would it be okay to throw or assert in a custom implementation?

Answer (score 10):

As usual in C++ Standard, when nothing is stated explicitly, violating the requirements leads to undefined behavior. *Shall* means *at all times must*, it's a requirement, not an option in C++ Standard.

For example here's what [MSDN says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5t5fykhz.aspx):

> The pointer _Ptr must have been returned earlier by a call to allocate for an allocator object that compares equal to *this, allocating an array object of the same size and type.

which means that the size must match precisely, otherwise you run into undefined behavior.

Comment: @FrEEzE - The implementation can ignore the parameter because it knows what it **has** to be. Other implementations might use it, if they don't remember the allocation size themselves.

Comment: Ignoring size is one of valid kinds of undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't say. Which means that it would be the nasty "undefined behviour".

Comment: Yes, I know. But I want to know if it would be okay to throw or assert (in a custom implementation) when size doesn't match the allocated size.

Comment: If it is undefined, you can do whatever you want. The standard containers will surely pass the correct value. For your own containers **you** can define the behavior. :-)

Answer (score 1):

This is present in the standard to allow for underlying allocators that do not know the size of an allocation from its pointer.

For example, the AmigaOS allocator maintains a list of free memory blocks and even allows partial deallocation (i.e. if I allocate 1024 bytes, then free 512 bytes at offset 256, I end up with two 256 byte allocations), so the allocator expects me to pass this information to the deallocator.